# Cannot setup Windows Authentication without a valid commercial license

Tags: ravendb, nservicebus, nservicebus4

NServiceBus 3+ uses RavenDB for persistence by default. Several articles ([this](http://ravendb.net/nservicebus-and-ravendb), [this](http://www.udidahan.com/2011/07/22/nservicebus-and-ravendb-better-together/) and [this](http://particular.net/articles/using-ravendb-in-nservicebus-installing)) mention that as long as RavenDB is used only to store NServiceBus data (Subscription, Saga, Timeouts), NServiceBus license is enough and separate RavenDB license is not required. However, the current version of RavenDB (Build 2700) doesn't allow the authentication to be setup on the server and throws below error (`Cannot setup Windows Authentication without a valid commercial license`). Does this mean that we can no longer use RavenDB (at least the latest version) with NServiceBus without a separate license? This works fine at least until build 2380. That is when the version is changed from v2.0 to v2.5. Using persistence without authentication is not an option as while Subscription and Timeouts are NServiceBus specific data, sagas can and do contain sensitive data that cannot be allowed to be accessible via http to everyone (even within LAN). Buying a license for RavenDB is not that big an issue but so far we understood that we only need NServiceBus license as long as RavenDB is not used for anything other than NServiceBus data. It would be great to get a clarification on this from NServiceBus or RavenDB team.

```
Server Error:
-----------------------------------------
/bulk_docs
Raven.Abstractions.Exceptions.OperationVetoedException: PUT vetoed by Raven.Database.Server.Security.Triggers.WindowsAuthPutTrigger because: Cannot setup Windows Authentication without a valid commercial license.
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.AssertPutOperationNotVetoed(String key, RavenJObject metadata, RavenJObject document, TransactionInformation transactionInformation) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:line 931
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass4b.<Put>b__43(IStorageActionsAccessor actions) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:line 779
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Batch(Action`1 action) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Storage\Esent\TransactionalStorage.cs:line 605
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.Put(String key, Etag etag, RavenJObject document, RavenJObject metadata, TransactionInformation transactionInformation) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:line 772
   at Raven.Database.Extensions.CommandExtensions.Execute(ICommandData self, DocumentDatabase database, BatchResult batchResult) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Extensions\CommandExtensions.cs:line 50
   at Raven.Database.Extensions.CommandExtensions.ExecuteBatch(ICommandData self, DocumentDatabase database) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Extensions\CommandExtensions.cs:line 23
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.ProcessBatch(IList`1 commands) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:line 2086
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass107.<Batch>b__103(IStorageActionsAccessor actions) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:line 2048
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.ExecuteBatch(Action`1 action, EsentTransactionContext transactionContext) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Storage\Esent\TransactionalStorage.cs:line 663
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Batch(Action`1 action) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Storage\Esent\TransactionalStorage.cs:line 615
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.Batch(IList`1 commands) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:line 2046
   at Raven.Database.Server.Responders.DocumentBatch.Batch(IHttpContext context) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Server\Responders\DocumentBatch.cs:line 124
   at Raven.Database.Server.Responders.DocumentBatch.Respond(IHttpContext context) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Server\Responders\DocumentBatch.cs:line 41
   at Raven.Database.Server.HttpServer.DispatchRequest(IHttpContext ctx) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Server\HttpServer.cs:line 782
   at Raven.Database.Server.HttpServer.HandleActualRequest(IHttpContext ctx) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Server\HttpServer.cs:line 645
-----------------------------------------    
   at Raven.Studio.Infrastructure.InvocationExtensions.Catch(Task parent, Func`2 func)
   at Raven.Studio.Infrastructure.InvocationExtensions.Catch(Task parent, Action`1 action)
   at Raven.Studio.Infrastructure.InvocationExtensions.Catch(Task parent)
   at Raven.Studio.Infrastructure.Command.Execute(Object parameter)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.ExecuteCommand()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(Control ctrl, EventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName, UInt32 flags)



Client side exception:
System.Net.WebException: [HttpWebRequest_WebException_RemoteServer]
Arguments: NotFound
Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=5.1.20125.0&File=System.Windows.dll&Key=HttpWebRequest_WebException_RemoteServer
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Func`2.Invoke(T arg)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise)
```

Comment: we also plan so ship the raven license inside NServiceBus in a future version https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/1496

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you contacted NServiceBus support?
We will gladly send you a RavenDB license, just contact us!

Comment: Thanks. Doing it now.

Comment: If u need it today, send me an email directly.

Comment: We are good for today. The dev still is on build 2380. Rolling out in production in next few weeks and for that I upgraded to the latest version and ran into this issue.

Comment: It would be nice to document this somewhere. It isn't mentioned anywhere or at least I could not locate it.

Comment: Agree, we will document this.

Comment: Btw, ravendb v2.5 is not supported yet with nservicebus!

Comment: Ah... I updated the samples to use RavenDB 2.5 (unauthenticated) and those worked. Haven't updated our projects yet. Looks like I shouldn't :) I noticed a few discussions on Github also. Do you have some estimate (rough is fine) to when it would be supported officially?

Comment: This is the issue that most concern us, https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ravendb/FP2Tr_32jJk/QiKjc9RhTC0J

Comment: Contcted Particular support, got the license and it works fine.